# Drawable-mpdi on Xoom and HTC mobile

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, drawable

I am developing app for Mobiles(HTC) and Motorola Xoom. But the problem i am facing is that both Uses Drawable-mpdi bitmaps.
abd there is difference in screen size of both, The Image which is perfect on Mobile is became very small on Tablet.

I have checked the [list for Drawable folders used by devices.](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/)
Please Help me how to sort out this Problem ?
How can I make different size images for both of devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this.  Hopefully, other people will add more.

You could use the MDPI folder with a single image of high enough resolution for the tablet then let Android scale it for smaller devices using the scale properties of an ImageView.  However, you are focusing only on HTC and Xoom and that doesn't solve your problem for devices which use other generic resolutions.

Or, you could use the drawable-nodpi folder and have several images with your own resolution naming scheme e.g. myimagesmall.bmp, myimagemedium.bmp etc.  Then at runtime, measure the device screen size and DPI and load the appropriate image.

Or, combine them.  Use nodpi and a single image and let Android scale for you.  Using BitmapFactory, you can control dithering and anti-aliasing to get good results.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmmm tahnks for reply Simon. I will try this "Then at runtime, measure the device screen size and DPI and load the appropriate image."

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about density, Motorola XOOM also uses mdpi drawables, so to differenciate drawables between tablets and small phones you should use folders with respect to screen sizes. Phone screen size is usually treated as normal, and a 10-inch tablet is xlarge, so drawable-xlarge-mdpi is the folder name you should use to place drawables for 10-inch tablets. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

> The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.
>
> Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the above size groups are deprecated and you should instead use the swdp configuration qualifier to define the smallest available width required by your layout resources. For example, if your multi-pane tablet layout requires at least 600dp of screen width, you should place it in layout-sw600dp/. Using the new techniques for declaring layout resources is discussed further in the section about